# why the page not redirect to with www?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

In my site's root directory, i create a file named `.htaccess`. and put the following code into it.but when i access  **example.com/test.html**.

It not redirect to http://www.example.com/test.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC];
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

thank you, what's the reason of it?

Comment: Be caz itz nou leik youz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the second line.

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I wouldn't use %{HTTP_HOST} as then the processor has to parse that, which may be small, but can scale up on a heavy server